# SMD Potentiometers, with long and standing wiper

Tags: surface-mount, potentiometer, through-hole

I am trying to find a component, but I am not sure if such a component exists.

I want the potentiometer with the standing wiper, like this:
[image]

However, all the potentiometers that I find of this type (standing wiper) are through hole components.
Does anyone know if this can be found as SMD as well?

Ideally, I would like the wiper to be long as well, but that is another story.

Comment: In this market, and depending on the production quantity & application, clip and bend the leads for instant SMT! (mildly joking) SMT rotary pots do seem like a rarity.   Perhaps manufactures don't like the leveraged force produced by the long arm connected to the PCB SMT pads?  I dunno.

Comment: By "standing wiper" I assume you mean a protruding shaft? Yes, hard to find but they do exist. Here's an example from Mouser: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Alps-Alpine/RK1191124001?qs=YMSFtX0bdJDxC%2FSZguQ0Ow%3D%3D

Comment: Why not use a panel mount pot and wire it to the PCB?

Comment: Chris has a point - with no mounting hardware, all of the force is upon a few SMT pads - recipe for breaking.  Consider a hand-soldered through-hole part for reliability.